# XPM - Update Preview error

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5

So XPM/Session Preview was working fine - until now!

Now all I get is the following error appear in notifications when I update preview:

> Unable to update session data: An error occured while invoking method
>   'public abstract com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta
>   com.tridion.storage.dao.ItemDAO.findByPrimaryKey(int,int,com.tridion.storage.dao.ItemTypeSelector)
>   throws com.tridion.broker.StorageException' for dao
>   com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAItemDAO@7cbe9f8f

Is there anyway to move past this?

Cheers

Comment: Seems to be something wrong in the preview service session database connectivity, based on above error update preview reaches to preview service and failed in the storage layer, you can check the preview service cd_core or cd_preview error logs to find out more information